# Ideas on how to remember previous user selections on .NET WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am currently looking at a better approach to remember/persist previous state of the controls on a .NET Windows Form.

For example, there are 5 drop down list menu controls on a windows form. And user previously selected some items in these drop down menu. What I'd like to do here is: when this WinForm is loaded again, user's previous selections shall be recovered and remain the same.

For now, I can kinda think of a solution: store each selected value/index in a text file or registry key or something. And then read them every time the From is loaded.

But the thing is this approach would become inefficient to deal with a large number of controls and maintain their states.

So can anyone give me some thoughts or suggestions? What'd be the best way to do achieve it?

EDIT:

I just had a read about [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx) on MSDN, and this concerns me because I am doing the add-in project at the moment:

> You cannot use application settings in an unmanaged application that
>   hosts the .NET Framework. Settings will not work in such environments
>   as Visual Studio add-ins, C++ for Microsoft Office, control hosting in
>   Internet Explorer, or Microsoft Outlook add-ins and projects.

Comment: The link you referenced in your Edit is actually talking about the App.config file. The *.settings file are actually user scope settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to look at Settings files

[Saving User Settings](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/350010/Saving-User-Settings-in-Winform-Application)

```
private void UserSettingsDemo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtServer.Text = Settings.Default.ServerNameSetting;
        txtDatabase.Text = Settings.Default.DBNameSetting;
        txtPassword.Text = Settings.Default.PasswordSetting;
        txtUserId.Text = Settings.Default.UserIdSetting;
    }

    private void UserSettingsDemo_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Settings.Default.DBNameSetting = txtDatabase.Text;
        Settings.Default.UserIdSetting = txtUserId.Text;
        Settings.Default.PasswordSetting = txtPassword.Text;
        Settings.Default.ServerNameSetting = txtServer.Text;
        Settings.Default.Save();

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about keeping the previous state of a control after restarting the application? In that case, you probably won't have no choice than writing all the changes down in an configuration file for example.

If you are trying to navigate between different winforms and want to persist the changes, you could implement an history of controls. A datastructur like a stack should do the trick, with the following methods:

AddToHistory(Control control)

RetrieveLastOpen()

Answer (score 1):

As far as you know what exactly you want to save it is ok to use smth like

```
(foreach var child in MainForm.Children.OfType<ComboBox>)
{
    // Save properties of child into Dictionary<string, ComboBoxProperties>
}
```

and for loading you will do smth like this

```
(foreach var child in MainForm.Children.OfType<ComboBox>)
{
    // Load properties of child from dictionary[child.Name]
}
```